# How do I put the Service in the Controller constructor using typescript?

Tags: typescript, api, rest, backend

I'm making a simple REST API with typescript that calls your classes to check a database in this order: `Controller > Service > Repository`.

So I tried these codes:

### **Controller**:

```js
export class GetNurseController {
  constructor(private getNurseService: GetNurseService) {}

  async handle(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> {
    try {
      const { id } = req.authrocket.currentUser;
      const user = await this.getNurseService.execute(id);

      return res.json({ user });
    } catch (err: any) {
      return res.status(500).json({ err });
      // That json return an empty err object, but in my console, an undefined error for
      // "getNurseService" is printed.
    }
  }
}
```

### **Router**:

```js
const nurseRepository = new NurseRepository();
const getNurseService = new GetNurseService(nurseRepository);
const getNurseController = new GetNurseController(getNurseService);

const nurseRoutes = Router();
nurseRoutes.get('/', requireLogin, getNurseController.handle);
```

### **I also tried this Controller**:

```js
export class GetNurseController {
  public NurseRepository: INurseRepository;
  public getNurseService: GetNurseService;

  constructor() {
    this.nurseRepository = new NurseRepository();
    this.getNurseService = new GetNurseService(this.nurseRepository);
  }

  async handle(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> {
    try {
      const { id } = req.authrocket.currentUser;
      const user = await this.getNurseService.execute(id);

      return res.json({ user });
    } catch (err: any) {
      return res.status(500).json({ err });
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to access this route with code like this I always get an empty error or sometimes my browser refuses the connection.

But, when I change the code to this:

### **Controller**:

```js
export class GetNurseController {
  async handle(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> {
    try {
      const nurseRepository = new nurseRepository();
      const getNurseService = new GetNurseService(nurseRepository);

      const { id } = req.authrocket.currentUser;
      const user = await getNurseService.execute(id);

      return res.json({ user });
    } catch (err: any) {
      return res.status(500).json({ err });
    }
  }
}
```

### **Router**:

```js
const getNurseController = new GetNurseController();

const nurseRoutes = Router();
nurseRoutes.get('/', requireLogin, getNurseController.handle);
```

Works well. Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong, or if what I'm trying to do is possible, please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question with more details? It is unclear what your issue is and the code by itself is not enough for us to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that the issue is how you pass the handler. You're doing that in a way that loses its reference to `this`.

Instead of this line:

```js
nurseRoutes.get('/', requireLogin, getNurseController.handle);
```

You need *either* one of these:

```js
nurseRoutes.get(
  '/',
  requireLogin,
  getNurseController.handle.bind(getNurseController)
);
```

```js
nurseRoutes.get(
  '/',
  requireLogin,
  (req: Request, res: Response) => getNurseController.handle(req, res)
);
```